# c# htmlagilitypack - how to extract specific text from web page

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to extract the description from
http://www.wowhead.com/quest=35151/your-base-your-choice
and show it into a richTextBox control.

The output should be:

> You have already constructed an impressive garrison in Frostfire. I
>   believe I should defer this next choice to you. One region of Gorgrond
>   is rich in resources. A lumber mill could help us make the most of
>   them. Another region harbors hardened gladiators. A sparring arena
>   would help persuade them to fight for our cause. Either path will
>   strengthen us as we seek to find and weaken the Iron Horde. Which do
>   you choose, Commander?

Below is the code I've tried so far.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.wowhead.com/quest=35151"));            
            var root = html.DocumentNode;
            var p = root.Descendants("h2")
                .Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                .Equals("heading-size-3"))
                .FirstOrDefault().NextSibling;
            richTextBox1.Text = p.InnerText;
```

But all I get is:

> You have already constructed an impressive garrison in Frostfire. I
>   believe I should defer this next choice to you.

I apologise for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all siblings between first `.heading-size-3`, till next header `.heading-size-3`

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.wowhead.com/quest=35151"));
var root = html.DocumentNode;
var descriptionHeader = root.Descendants("h2")
    .Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
    .Equals("heading-size-3"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
var current = descriptionHeader.NextSibling;
var result = "";
while(current != null && !current.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
    .Equals("heading-size-3"))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(current.InnerText))
    {
        result += " "+current.InnerText;
    }
    current = current.NextSibling;
}
richTextBox1.Text = result;
```

At the end, you will receive:

> You have already constructed an impressive garrison in Frostfire. I believe I should defer this next choice to you.
>   One region of Gorgrond is rich in resources. A lumber mill could help us make the most of them.
>   Another region harbors hardened gladiators. A sparring arena would help persuade them to fight for our cause.
>   Either path will strengthen us as we seek to find and weaken the Iron Horde.
>   Which do you choose, Commander?